# Is there a way to interactively filter a datatable through a cell click in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

This a basic skeleton of an R shiny application that I'm using to test cell click drilldowns in R. Through this code I can see that the cell value is being printed with each click:

```
ui.R

library(shiny)

fluidPage(
  title = 'DataTables Information',
  h1('A client-side table'),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('x6'))
  ),
  hr(),
  h1('A table using server-side processing'),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('x4')),
    column(6, verbatimTextOutput('x5'))
  )
)
```

Server script:

```
server.R
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # render the table (with row names)
  output$x6 = DT::renderDataTable(mtcars, server = TRUE)

  output$x4 = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars, selection = 'single')
  }, server = TRUE) 

  output$x5 = renderPrint({
    cat('cell value:\n\n')
    cat(input$x4_cell_clicked$value, sep = ', ')
    cat('\n\nAll rows:\n\n')
    cat(input$x4_rows_all, sep = ', ')
    cat('\n\nSelected rows:\n\n')
    cat(input$x4_rows_selected, sep = ', ')
  })

  observeEvent(input$x4_rows_selected, {
    validate(need(!is.null(input$x4_cell_clicked), ''))
    print("You clicked something!")
  })

  observeEvent(input$x4_rows_selected, {
    validate(need(!is.null(input$x4_cell_clicked), ''))
    info <- input$x4_cell_clicked$value

  })

})
```

I am trying to get the top table labeled 'x6' to dynamically filter everytime I click on a cell in the bottom table labeled 'x4'. I attempted to do this through proxy with this code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # render the table (with row names)
  output$x6 = DT::renderDataTable(mtcars, server = TRUE)

  output$x4 = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars, selection = 'single')
  }, server = TRUE) 

  output$x5 = renderPrint({
    cat('cell value:\n\n')
    cat(input$x4_cell_clicked$value, sep = ', ')
    cat('\n\nAll rows:\n\n')
    cat(input$x4_rows_all, sep = ', ')
    cat('\n\nSelected rows:\n\n')
    cat(input$x4_rows_selected, sep = ', ')
  })

  observeEvent(input$x4_rows_selected, {
    validate(need(!is.null(input$x4_cell_clicked), ''))
    print("You clicked something!")
  })

  myProxy = DT::dataTableProxy('x6')

  observeEvent(input$x4_rows_selected, {
    validate(need(!is.null(input$x4_cell_clicked), ''))
    info <- input$x4_cell_clicked$value

  })

  # reset last selected value using the proxy
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
  DT::selectRows(myProxy, NULL)
     validate(need(!is.null(input$x4_cell_clicked), ''))
     myProxy <- myProxy %>% 
       filter(mpg == input$x4_cell_clicked$value)
     output$x6 = DT::renderDataTable(myProxy, server = TRUE)
  })
})
```

The 'x6' table is not updating with cell clicks though. I just need to understand how a value from a cell can be dynamically accessed through observeEvent functions to influence other figures or drilldown. For an initial test case I would like the 'x6' table to filter by column mpg when I click on a cell within the mpg column in the 'x4' table. Sorry if this explanation is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking too hard with proxy, just need to make x6's data reactive with input from x4

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'DataTables Information',
  h1('A client-side table'),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('x6'))
  ),
  hr(),
  h1('A table using server-side processing'),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('x4'))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- reactive({

    temp <- mtcars

    if (is.null(input$x4_rows_selected)) {
      temp <- mtcars
    }
    else {
      select <- mtcars[input$x4_rows_selected,]

      temp <- mtcars[mtcars$mpg == select$mpg,]
    }

    return(temp)

  })


  output$x6 = DT::renderDataTable(dat(), server = TRUE)

  output$x4 = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars, selection = 'single')
  }, server = TRUE) 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```